# Regex not match with logical OR

Tags: regex

Need to match words that doesn't start with `tss-` or equal to `tss`. Tried multiple combinations but no positive results.

```
^(((?!(tss)).*)|(?!tss-).+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply two negative lookahead checks against the input string, you need to simply chain them after the `^` anchor:

```js
^(?!tss$)(?!tss-).*
```

The logical relationship is AND in this case:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!tss$)` - the string must not be  equal to `tss`
- AND
- `(?!tss-)` - the string must not start with `tss-`
- `.*` - match the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If the words can also occur in a sentence, you might also use lookarounds to assert not tss followed by either a whitespace bounadry or `-` using a negative lookahead.

```
(?<!\S)(?!tss(?:(?!\S)|-))\S+
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert to the right is not

  - `tss` Match literally
  - `(?:(?!\S)|-)` Match either a whitespace boundary or `-`
- `)` Close Lookahead
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gi8kiY/1)